# NDI-PYTHON live streaming

Tags: python, streaming, live, ndi

I have a live stream project like ptz cameras,i have using NDI SDK using backend,framework PYHTON Fastapi,but i can't understand or i don't know how to integrate NDI to python,simple using NDI in python for live streaming purposes.anyone shared knowledge and guide to me .

using NDI in python for live streaming purposes